# How do I get higher precision geohash of a lower precision geohash in an optimize way

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas

I have a requirement to get higher precision geohashes of a lower precision geohash in efficient way (instead of converting to lon lat and then encode again ).
I have found solution in other way where higher precision geohashes convert to lower precision geohash boxes.

What I am trying to do out of above is to get lower precision boxes of a big polygon and then convert them to higher precision. This way I can paralyze the geohash conversion for a very big polygon.

I would like to do this using python

Comment: Could you explain what is the goal? Geohash at some precision represents a rectangular box. Next level breaks this rectangle into four, then each of the four is broken into four again - which one do you want to select?

Comment: Ex. When I given length 4 geohash it will return length 5 geohash list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> given length 4 geohash it will return length 5 geohash list

This is pretty straightforward - each letter in geohash encodes 5-bit (32 potential values) of the quad-tree. All 32 values are possible and represent different areas inside parent geohash rectangle, so if you want to get list of all the possible longer geohash values, just append these letters.

The list of 32 digits and letters used by geohash [can be found in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash#Textual_representation) or any geohash implementation: "0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz". Just append each of these to shorter geohash, and you'll get all the possible longer ones.

Comment: Michael Entin Thank you for the well explained answer.